# rails check_box_tag set checked with default value

Tags: ruby-on-rails, checkbox, arguments

I currently have a rails check_box_tag call that looks like

```
check_box_tag #{name}
```

I want to include a checked attribute, which I know I can do with

```
check_box_tag name, value, checked
```

But what if I want to set it to checked without explicitly specifying `value` (I just want to use the default). Or similarly, what if I wanted to specify html options without specifying the `checked` attribute. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: I don't understand why you don't want to set a value. Can you give a use case?

Comment: Or let's just say I want to set an HTML attribute without explicitly specifying the checked state (I just want to use the default) - same issue I believe.

Answer (score 20):

Just wanted to update this.  The third parameter for `check_box_tag` is a boolean value representing the checked status.

```
check_box_tag name, value, true
```

Comment: What is "value" in this case?

Comment: @Akron I had the same question! So I asked, and the answers are [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67554956/how-does-the-argument-value-in-check-box-tag-work?noredirect=1#comment119411961_67554956) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67554956/how-does-the-argument-value-in-check-box-tag-work?noredirect=1#comment119412313_67554956)

Answer (score 8):

If you want the checkbox to be checked, then

```
check_box_tag name, value, {:checked => "checked"}
```

otherwise

```
check_box_tag name, value
```

Answer (score 8):

**check_box_tag**(name, value = "1", checked = false, options = {})

Examples:

```
check_box_tag 'receive_email', 'yes', true
# => <input checked="checked" id="receive_email" name="receive_email" type="checkbox" value="yes" />

check_box_tag 'tos', 'yes', false, class: 'accept_tos'
# => <input class="accept_tos" id="tos" name="tos" type="checkbox" value="yes" />

check_box_tag 'eula', 'accepted', false, disabled: true
# => <input disabled="disabled" id="eula" name="eula" type="checkbox" value="accepted" />
```

<kbd>[api.rubyonrails.org](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormTagHelper.html#method-i-check_box_tag)</kbd>

Answer (score 4):

There are no ways to do it directly. But the `check_box_tag` implementation is trivial, you can monkey patch it or create own helper.

Original implementation:

```
  def check_box_tag(name, value = "1", checked = false, options = {})
    html_options = { "type" => "checkbox", "name" => name, "id" => sanitize_to_id(name), "value" => value }.update(options.stringify_keys)
    html_options["checked"] = "checked" if checked
    tag :input, html_options
  end
```

Answer (score 4):

If you pass in a value of "1" to the value field, it will pass-on the value of the real state of the checkbox, regardless of the checked default value:

```
is_checked = <default boolean>

check_box_tag :show_defaults, '1', is_checked
```

(now always reflects user input)

Comment: Is there a way to prevent the checkbox from passing the state along with the values? I'm getting an array of values which I expect but also the word "on".

Answer (score 2):

If anyone have column type boolean then look at this. is_checked? will be default boolean value. It worked for me.

`<%= hidden_field_tag :name, 'false' %>
<%= check_box_tag :name, true, is_checked? %>`

Comment: by using this technique, DOM generates error about 2 elements having same ID.