# Show Checked Records on Rails Edit Form - Many to Many

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have two forms where I can create and edit users. Each of these users has a many to many relationship with my location model. On my form, for a given user, you can check/uncheck locations that this user is associated with. Here is my code to render the locations:

```
<% @locations.each do |i| %>
      <li class="list-group-item">
          <%= check_box_tag "locations[]", i.id %>
          <%= i.name %>
       </li>
<% end %>
```

This code works fine when creating the users and checking their associated locations, but I obviously have no way of displaying the associated locations on edit. I want the previously associated locations to be automatically checked. What is the most efficient way of achieving this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: you can do `check_box_tag "locations[]", i.id, checked: user.location_ids.include?(i.id)`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [rails check\_box\_tag set checked with default value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11796629/rails-check-box-tag-set-checked-with-default-value)

Comment: I was able to use `<%= check_box_tag "locations[]", i.id, @user.location_ids.include?(i.id) %>` and got it to work.  I didn't know about the `location_ids` method. Makes sense now. Thanks! @MrYoshiji

Comment: Rails offers you a lot of useful methods: it generated for you 4 methods for the `has_many :locations, through: :some_join_records` relation: 2 getters `locations` and `location_ids` and 2 setters `locations=(array_of_locations_object)` and `location_ids=(array_of_location_ids)`. But **beware**, the setters works differently if the primary object is persisted or not.  Doing `User.new.location_ids = [1,2,3]` will build but not persist the locations, but doing `User.last.location_ids = [1,2,3]` will actually trigger insertions and will try to persist the data (!!!!!)