# How does the argument "value" in check_box_tag work?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-6

The docs for [`check_box_tag`](https://apidock.com/rails/v6.0.0/ActionView/Helpers/FormTagHelper/check_box_tag) are as follows:

> check_box_tag(name, value = "1", checked = false, options = {}) public

> Creates a check box form input tag.

What is the `value` argument?

I have provided many different values to the `value` parameter in my own checkbox form, yet the checkbox seems to work the same (it works, I just want to know what `value` is doing?).

It seems [some others](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11796629/rails-check-box-tag-set-checked-with-default-value/37036148#comment107350562_25414895) are also confounded by it.

#### Example

These do the same thing in my application (they both work perfectly, which I wouldn't have expected):

```
<%= check_box_tag :approved, "hi there", user.approved? %>
```

```
<%= check_box_tag :approved, "1", user.approved? %>
```

Comment: the HTML from both those is exactly the same, can you show what the HTML output on those is? (is it what is put into the first answer below for both of those examples?)

Comment: @RockwellRice Appreciate the help. I ended up using `check_box` (rather than `check_box_tag`) so I stopped trying to figure it out. But the surprising thing was that the `value` argument didn't seem to affect the operability of the form - when submitted checked, it would set the boolean in the db to true, and when submitted unchecked, it would set the boolean to false (even when the `value` was something intentionally silly, like "hi there").

Comment: The actual casting happens later in the model if you have a boolean colum. Any truthy value except `'0'`, `'false'` ,`'FALSE'`, `'f'`, and `'F'` is true.  `''` is treated as nil. https://stackoverflow.com/a/60769537/544825

Comment: @max if I reword the question to 'how does value in check_box_tag work?", would you be happy to make your comment into an answer? I feel like I'm not the only one to not know how exactly how this works, so it could be useful to others too.

Answer (score 1):

The value argument refers to the boolean value in the db.

- If the checkbox is unchecked then the value will be '0' and the boolean will be set to `false`
- If you check the checkbox then the value will be '1' and the boolean will be set to `true`

This is the way checkboxes work in Rails and it doesn't mind if you want to pass a custom value like `value='ilovemydog'` or something else, it will always refer to '0' or '1'.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have much experience with ERB but the method gets converted to simple HTML as

```
<input id="accept" name="accept" type="checkbox" value="1" />
```

The value attribute is used when using the input tag with forms, now when the form is submitted and the checkbox is checked, the value is passed as "accept=1"